# delay, html(' '), on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code. First keypress is work for clear element, something like when I press the 1, 2, 3 keys it clears after 3s.

But when I extend my text in my input text, lets say 123 and I add 4th char it shows again, but never clears or empties my element,

This one is for autocomplete.

```
$(document).on('keyup','.autotry',function(){   
   var lenght = $(this).val().length;
   if(lenght >= 3){
      var req = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url : "autocomplete.php",
        data : {acc: 'autos' , req : req},
        success : function(auto){
          $('.auto').html(auto).delay(3000).queue(function() {
             $(this).html('');
          });
        }
      });           
   }
})
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the time to read "[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)". Where is `lenght` defined?

Comment: ...and did you really consistently mis-spell it? (It's spelled `length`, not `lenght`. If you did it right in one place but wrong in the other, that's probably part of your problem.)

Comment: sorry, i delete some code for css. so make this code lil shoter. length is var for my input char lenght, sorry.

Comment: You're calling `queue()` without calling `dequeue()` from the callback (or calling the provided `next()` function). Mayhem will ensue.

Comment: Frédéric Hamidi : Thanks alot man, you solve my queastion, please answer something so i cand give you green check.

Comment: @Ricky, I'll do more than that -- here is a link to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/), which contains several examples.

Comment: thanks Frédéric Hamidi, please post something. =) i want give you greend check or rep